# Can I delete the android and ios folders in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am writing for desktop, so *windows, linux, and mac* directories are all I need. But I am not sure if I should delete the android and ios folders or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, because unless you are compiling your code for this platform, its contents are useless to you, as they are only a boilerplate code for you.

Example, if you enable web support for Flutter, but decide not to compile for web, then removing the folder does literally nothing to your code if you're (for example) developing for Android and iOS only.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the command line to **delete** or **create** folders of flutter env.

For example, to delete android:

```
rm -r android
```

and if you want to deploy for android in the future
you can use:

```
flutter create --platforms=android .
```

so feel free to delete or create any env.

Answer (score -1):

I'm use the command line rm -r nameFolder

```
rm -r linux
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).